# VideoView fails to play video on certain devices

Tags: android, android-videoview

After recording a `.mp4` video from a Samsung Galaxy S4 and uploading it to a server, I try to stream it on my Nexus 5 device in a `VideoView` which fails and Logcat shows this

```
E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-2147483648)
D/MediaPlayer﹕ Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
```

The video turns out to be around `4.82mb` and is recorded via intents

```
//VIDEO CAMERA
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent( MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 20);
cameraIntent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1 );
startActivityForResult( cameraIntent, TAKE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE );
```

The recorded video is playing properly on the Samsung device, and also when I download the file from the server to my PC it plays properly. I have tried downloading the file to my Nexus device and it still fails to play, tried to stream it within the `VideoView` and it fails with errors mentioned above each time. I have tried uploading a video from Nexus 5 and the Samsung device plays it properly. I am at a lost as to why this is happening, has anyone encountered a similar problem and found a fix or maybe I am doing something wrong?

## Edit

It fails to play in any of the systems video players as well, but still plays on the original Samsung device.
Also I have tested a lower resolution and it works then, so now I think I need to find a way to change the resolution after video capture or send an instruction to use a certain resolution if possible. Any help with this aspect?

Answer (score 0):

These messages are not indicative of an error:

```
E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-2147483648)
D/MediaPlayer﹕ Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
```

You get these because streaming content can only be opened on the server side.  You should get another error after these, e.g. Error (1,-1001).  Most likely the S4 uses a profile that is not supported on Nexus 5.

As for resolution, the intent API you are using only supports 2 quality settings (high and low).  Low means really low, and is device dependent.

To have more control over a video capture, you could use the Camera and the MediaRecorder interface.  There is a guide at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video.

For a more advanced example, there is a sample project at http://developer.android.com/samples/MediaRecorder/index.html.